# Meaning of a Probability Distribution over a finite set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a finite $A=\{a_i,\,i=1,2\}$ and a finite set $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ and define a probability distribution over the set $B$. Denote this by $\Pi(B)$.

Suppose also that we define a function $S:A\to\Pi(B)$.

In many instances, I have seen the notation $s\in S$. Can we do this? If yes, what is its meaning?

My understanding is that the function $S$ maps elements of $A$ into $\Pi(B)$ and we can write $s(a_i)\in S(A)$. Do we abuse notation by writing $s\in S$?

Can we be more specific about $\Pi(B)$, for example, is it a set? Can we explicitly expand it? Can we write $\Pi(B)=[0,1]$?

I'd appreciate any help or hint.

These questions arise from studying the Bayesian game in Game Theory literature.

Comment: Can you add an example of where this notation occurs?

Comment: @mimuller See paper "Transition Models of Equilibrium Assessment in Bayesian Game," 2015 by Kiminao Kogiso. In particular, see the formulation on page 5997.